# How applicable can Martian soil samples from a handful of sites be to Mars at large?

Tags: mars, colonization

Martian soil samples have been said to be heavily contaminated with perchlorate salts, which will obviously have tremendous impact on efforts to colonize Mars. But what reason do we have to believe that these samples are representative of Mars in general, and not merely a localized concentration at the sample site? Is it possible that the sample was taken from something like Death Valley, where a soil sample would reveal heavy concentrations of borax?

Comment: We would know when we have got much more samples from many sites but not earlier.

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of what I'm thinking - but I'm not a geologist, and there may be some reason why they're more broadly applicable than it seems.

Comment: I would imagine we can get some idea of sites we haven't landed at via spectroscopy performed by orbiters.

Comment: Death Valley? Borax? Wellp, see you all in like 2-3 hours I'll probably be stuck in a Wikipedia tunnel of Death Valley facts.

Comment: I haven't seen any assumption on the part of scientists is applicable to the whole planet.

Comment: @GdD  Maybe because the perchlorate salts were found in dust, and dust tends to spread about the whole planet with the storms, one might say the contamination is appropriate for the whole planet at large.

Comment: @GdD - that is the kind of stuff I'm looking for. If you can develop that with something to support that assumption, that would be a good answer candidate.